# Invalid datatype function

Tags: types, sml

The function getElement doesn't work. I think the problem is the cart type definition, but I don't know why.

```
datatype element = FIRE | LAND | WATER

datatype pokemon = PIKACHU | CHARMANDER | BULBASUR

datatype power = int

type cart = pokemon*power*element

val newcart = (BULBASUR, 34, WATER)

fun getElement (c: cart) = (#3)c

val element = getElement newcart
```

Comment: Hi David, and welcome to StackOverflow! Try and be more descriptive than "it doesn't work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you wrote this:

```
datatype power = int
```

but clearly what you want is this:

```
type power = int
```

The problem with `datatype power = int` is that it declares a new type `power` with a single constructor, written "`int`", which just happens to be spelled exactly the same way as the name of the type `int`. For example, with your original code, the value `(BULBASUR, int, WATER)` has type `cart`, whereas `(BULBASUR, 34, WATER)` does not.

When you fix it to `type power = int`, the value `(BULBASUR, 34, WATER)` will have type `cart`.